# What word(s) can be used to describe person(s) who assume to outrank others because of their profession in a company?

Tags: adjectives

My reading case study mentioned that there are a group of engineers in a company who usually look down to other people in other departments because every major position within the company, including president and vice president, is occupied by engineers.

I look for a specific word to describe those people.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Please have a look at the checklist for the [tag:single-word-requests] tag. You seem to be missing some information for this category of questions. The checklist can be found in the 'info' link in the tag's tooltips (hover your mouse over the tag and click 'info').

Comment: an example sentence is always helpful in single word questions.

Comment: I edited question title.  Roll back if this does not better state you questions intent.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea if you can't think of the words "senior" and "superior", or if you're looking for a free collection of words to insult them with. Neither does anyone on this page. The answers are all over the map. This is not going anywhere. You will need to explain yourself better. What exactly you are trying to say, to whom exactly, in what kind of situation, and why.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who outranks you in a business would be referred to as your superior and those under you would be your subordinates.

Comment: But in the OP's context, the ones doing the 'looking down' might not actually be senior to the ones they look down upon. They just happen to be engineers when the bosses are also all engineers.

Comment: That's right. We may look for an adjective to describe them.

Comment: @Lawrence I see what you mean. I think I took the question too literally.

Comment: I thought similarly at first. What you answered was the question in the title.

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad

Comment: I edited question title. Roll back if this does not better state the questions intent.

Answer (score 0):

I would say they are "**self-important**", "**conceited**" or "**cocky**", since they think highly of themselves only because they are engineers.

> - [**self-importance**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-importance) - an exaggerated estimate of one's own importance.
> - [**conceited**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conceited) - (adj) having or showing an excessively high opinion of oneself a brilliant but conceited musician
> - [**cocky**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cocky) - (adj) having or showing confidence in a way that is annoying to other people

As a group, I'd say those guys are "part of a cocky club", "a cocky faction", or "a group of self-mportant employees".

Comment: How about their tendency? Would you mind if I ask for your help to describe their tendency? Do we have any specific word to characterize those engineer in this case?

Comment: @PhoenixElly   I don't think I understand what you mean by "their tendency".

Comment: There is more than 1 person who thinks they are important in the company just because they are engineers, that why I think there may be a word to describe a group of people like that.

Comment: @PhoenixElly  You might say they're a "cocky club", "a cocky faction", "a group of self-mportant employees".

Comment: I edited question title. Roll back if this does not better state questions intent.

Answer (score 0):

How about "the engineers in this company rule the roost"?

Answer (score -1):

an **unctuous** clique

**unctuous**. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unctuousTFD)

> 1. characterized by affected earnestness or moralistic fervor!